# In officer R, how to format text and bullet point levels for PowerPoint

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

So I am working on creating an automated powerpoint report in R using the officer package. I want to create a bulleted list with numerous levels but I need to be able to have specific text formatting for each line (i.e. I want the first two words to be green while the rest of the line is black). I tried using unordered_list() but this command doesn't allow the specific text formatting I need. I've tried the code below which colors/bolds the text that I want, but ph_add_par(level = ) does not indent the bullet points.

Is there a way that I can format the text how I want while also being able to manipulate the bullet point levels? I want it to look something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VYeL.png)

```
library(officer)
    report <- read_pptx()
    sprint_1 <- sprintf("%s total crimes in %s %s", 
                        tc20, params$month, params$year)

    report%>%
        add_slide(layout = 'Title and Content', master = 'Office Theme')%>%
      ph_with(value = "Academy: Summary Notes", location = ph_location_type(type = "title"))%>%
        ph_empty(location = ph_location_type("body")) %>%
        ph_add_par(level = 1L)%>%
        ph_add_text(str = sprint_1, style = fp_text(color = "black", font.size = 28, bold = TRUE, underlined = TRUE))%>%
        ph_add_par(level = 2L)%>%
        ph_add_text(str = paste("compared to this time in ", params$pastyear, " (", tc_ytd19, " total crimes)", sep = ""), 
                    style = fp_text(color = 'black', font.size = 24)) %>% 
        ph_add_text(str = paste(pct_chg_mth, "change", sep = " "),
                    style = fp_text(color = "green", font.size = 24)) -> report
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to run your code but the following code should help. Use `block_list` and in `ph_with` call set `level_list=c(1L, 2L, 1L)`

```
library(officer)

fpt_blue_bold <- fp_text(color = "#006699", bold = TRUE)
fpt_red_italic <- fp_text(color = "#C32900", italic = TRUE)

value <- block_list(
  fpar(ftext("hello world", fpt_blue_bold)),
  fpar(ftext("hello", fpt_blue_bold), " ",
       ftext("world", fpt_red_italic)),
  fpar(
    ftext("blah blah blah", fpt_red_italic)))
value

doc <- read_pptx()
doc <- add_slide(doc)
doc <- ph_with(doc, value, location = ph_location_type(type = "body"), 
               level_list = c(1L, 2L, 1L))
print(doc, target = "test.pptx")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey David! Thanks for the awesome package and for your response. But is there any way to indent the second and third bullet points while still keeping the text formatting?

Comment: no sorry, I'll add an option (I'd like to remove/deprecate ph_add_* functions)

Comment: I have updated my answer - to use that feature, you will need to update package from github until it goes on cran